# Is there a way to list/describe the ENI that is attached to an EC2 instance?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to write a python script to pull the ENI of all running EC2 instances.

If i run

```
for instance in ec2.instances.all():
    if instance.state["Name"] == "running":
        print("Id: {0}\n".format(instance.id))
```

For every running instance I get output:

Id: i-0xxxxxxxxx

What I'm trying to add on to that is the ENI of the EC2, but I'm having trouble finding an example of how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The ENIs are present in the `network_interfaces` attribute:

```
for instance in ec2.instances.filter(
        Filters=[
            {
                "Name": "instance-state-name",
                "Values": ["running"]
            }
        ]):
    print("Id: {0} {1}\n".format(
        instance.id,
        " ".join([eni.id for eni in instance.network_interfaces])
    )
```